# css file from highcharts is missing from highcharts site. need link to new css file

Tags: highcharts

I had a link for highcharts css file in my page.

The css is not loading and showing 404 (Not Found).

Please advice.

Regards
Joseph

Comment: the link was pointing to http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css

Comment: Hi,
I had downloaded the following highchart files. 

    stock highstock-1.3.2.js
    stock exporting-1.3.2.js
    highslide highslide-4.1.8.full.min.js
    highslide highslide-4.1.8.config.js
    http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css

I had created a graph with a popup using htmlExpand.
The code used to work, but now the pop up that comes up when clicking on the graphs does not display properly.

Following is the js fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/pX5XE/

Answer (score 1):

there's no css file just add this

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi,
I had downloaded the following highchart files. 

    stock/highstock-1.3.2.js
    stock/exporting-1.3.2.js
    highslide/highslide-4.1.8.full.min.js
    highslide/highslide-4.1.8.config.js
    http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css

I had created a graph with a popup using htmlExpand.
The code used to work, but now the pop up that comes up when clicking on the graphs does not display properly.

Following is the js fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/pX5XE/